# TypeError: Cannot read property 'follow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, whois

How do I get the value of this list to return to another function? I tried to use promise and async/await but it looks like it didn't work properly, now I have a problem with 'follow' of undefined, can someone help me

```
var parser = require("parse-whois");
var whois = require("node-whois");

async function getList(getRemainingDays = false) {
  let finalList = [];
  var domains = [
    "rundeck.compasso.com.br",
    "c.btg360.com.br",
    "api-prd.reservapto.com.br",
  ];
  try {
    for (let i = 2; i < domains.length; i++) {
      finalList.push(
        whois
          .lookup(domains[i])
          .then((data) => {
            let list = [];
            var dados = parser.parseWhoIsData(data);
            const expires = dados
              .filter((one) => one.attribute === "expires")
              .pop();
            const dateExpires = expires.value;
            list.push(domains[i]);
            list.push(dateExpires);
            return list;
          })

          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  let resultList = await Promise.all(finalList);
  return resultList;
}

async function test() {
  var list = await getList(true);

  console.log("");
  console.log(list);
  console.log("");
}

test();
```

Comment: This code doesn't mention the attribute `follow` even once... Please post a full stacktrace + the relevant code that it points to

Comment: exactly, that's just the code and has no follow

Comment: So what part of the whois code is causing the error? Is it the `parseWhoIsData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
const whois = require("whois-checker-v2");
        
    async function getList() {
            var domains = [
            "rundeck.compasso.com.br",
            "c.btg360.com.br",
            "api-prd.reservapto.com.br",
          ]
          let finalList = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
            finalList.push(
              (result = await whois
                .lookup(domains[i])
                .then((result) => {
                  var list = [];
                  list.push(domains[i]);
                  list.push(result.expirationDate);
                  return list;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  //console.log(err);
                }))
            );
          }
              let resultList = await Promise.all(finalList);
              return resultList;
            }
    
    async function test() {
      var lista = await getList();
      console.log(lista);
    }
    
    test();
```

result:

```
[
  [ 'c.btg360.com.br', '2023-02-16T03:00:00.000Z' ],
  [ 'api-prd.reservapto.com.br', '2022-12-03T03:00:00.000Z' ],
  [ 'api-prd.koerich.com.br', '2024-06-04T03:00:00.000Z' ],
  [ 'gmfy.compasso.com.br', '2025-06-13T03:00:00.000Z' ],
  [ 'compassouol.com.br', '2022-02-13T03:00:00.000Z' ],
  [ 'rancher.compasso.com.br', '2025-06-13T03:00:00.000Z' ]
]
```